# Can I compose a WCF callback contract out of multiple interfaces?

Tags: .net, wcf

Followup question to [How can I compose a WCF contract out of multiple interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502930/how-can-i-compose-a-wcf-contract-out-of-multiple-interfaces).

I tried to merge multiple callback interfaces in a single interface. This yields an InvalidOperationException claiming that the final interface contains no operations. Technically, this is true, however, the inherited interfaces do contain operations.

How can I fix this? Or is this a limitation of WCF?

Edit:

```
[ServiceContract]
// Using the following line instead would be no problem for me:
// [ServiceContract (CallbackContract = CallbackA)]
interface ServiceA { [OperationContract]void X(); }

[ServiceContract] // same here
interface ServiceB { [OperationContract]void Y(); }

interface CallbackA { [OperationContract]void CB_A() } // required in ServiceA
interface CallbackB { [OperationContract]void CB_B() } // required in ServiceB

interface CallbackC: CallbackA, CallbackB {} // composed callback contract

[ServiceContract (CallbackContract = CallbackC)]
interface ServiceC: ServiceA, ServiceB {} // composed service contract
```

Comment: Please attach some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to say without looking at the contract hierarchy of the service contract itself, but the answer may rely on this principle:

*`"A service contract can only designate a callback contract if that contract is a subinterface of all callback contracts defined by the contract's own base contracts."`*

- (Programming WCF Services, O'Reilly, see [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=DW2ldput788C&lpg=PA192&ots=qibzcxUIEP&dq=wcf%20callback%20contract%20inheritance&pg=PA191#v=onepage&q=&f=false) under "Callback Contract Hierarchy").

Comment: The service contract itself is built as described in the linked thread. It's a ServiceContract inheriting multiple ServiceContracts. These base interfaces do not specify any callback contract. However, I could change that so that every required callback contract is used as a callback contract in one of the service contract base interfaces.

Comment: Try as you now edited, adding that [ServiceContract (CallbackContract = CallbackA)] for CallbackA and CallbackB.

Comment: Ah, now I get the meaning of subinterface. Works perfectly now.